# Как подписаться на событие загрузки документа?

Tags: javascript, html

Как подписаться на событие загрузки документа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подписки на это событие необходимо установить функцию обратного вызова у тега <body> в вашем документе. Например:

```
<body onLoad="onBodyLoad()">
    <!-- остальная разметка -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

javascript:

```
window.onload = function() { ... }
```

или:

```
addEventListener(...); // для нормальных

attachEvent(...); // для ие
```

Answer (score 1):

window.onload вызовется после загрузки всего-всего, в т.ч. картинок, скриптов-счетчиков и проч., т.е. вполне возможно далеко не сразу (эти элементы начинают подтягивать свое содержимое после своего появления в документе).
Если надо запуститься по факту построения документа, лучше всего перед </body> добавить что-то типа <script type="text/javascript">DocInit();</script>, а уже в DocInit делать всю инициализацию.

Comment: Лучше тогда после </body> это сделать, иначе, если Вы попытаетесь что-нибудь сделать с тэгом до его полного формирования - нормальные браузеры сожрут, а вот всякие ие вылетят с ошибкой "Не удалось отобразить страницу".